# How do you open downloaded files in general?

Tags: files

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu and I have no idea how to open a file I've downloaded, there's nothing on the computer that can open it. It's a .jar file. It keeps asking for a program to use to open it, but there's nothing I can do.

Answer (score 0):

To *run* a jar file, you need Java runtime, either the openjdk version or the official oracle version. The file can be *opened* with the standard archive manager, which can handle most common archives except for `.rar` files.

Answer (score 0):

Install Java on your system with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

for the development kit or

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

for the runtime. If you just want to start a Java program, then the runtime environment is enough.

To start a java application in jar:

```
java -jar <your_jar_file>
```